# Foot and calves pain when running

Tags: injury-prevention, jogging

I know there seem to be a lot of similar questions, but most are about pain on the top of the foot. Mine is located on the inside of both feet when I run.

Here's my situation. I am extremely overweight (honestly I weigh around 290 for 6'0) and I have very flat feet. I did go and buy good shoes with thick gel soles (is that the right word? had to translate). The pain occurs only when I run after about 700m and quite rapidly wears off when I stop running. After my jog I feel no pain afterwards so I don't think I'm injured (yet). I also have the same pain in my calves but the foot pain is worse and makes me have to stop running even though I could still run.

Is this a matter of being overweight and having flat feet? Will losing weight make it better, and will I injure myself if I continue to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check with your Doctor**

- Clearance for exercise - First, congratulations on starting to exercise.  Based on your height and weight your [BMI](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/BMI-Body-Mass-Index.html), which is a body mass index used to screen for obesity, is 39.3 which suggests that you are in the obese category, Class II. In this case it is wise that you consult with your doctor and get clearance before beginning an exercise program.
- Diagnosis - Your doctor will be able to tell you the cause of your foot and calf pain.  It may be as you say, due to flat feet and your weight.  However, there may be [other causes](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-run-without-damaging-your-feet-knees-or-hips/965#965), as well as circulation problems.  Your doctor can tell you what is causing the pain and advise you on an appropriate exercise and nutrition program. If the problem is your flat feet, your doctor may prescribe [orthotics](http://www.runnersworld.com/subtopic/0,7123,s6-240-319-327-0,00.html). You may injure yourself if you continue to run on joints and tissue that cannot tolerate the impact of running.

**Alternatives to Running**

If the problem is from the impact of running, you may need to try alternatives to running until your body is better able to tolerate the workouts.  For instance,

- Walking will place less jarring compressive forces on your legs and spine than running or jogging.
- A stationary cycle causes no impact at all.
- Running or exercising in water also minimizes impact.
- [Nordic walking poles](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Nordic-Pole-Walking.html) with walking can give you more of a workout than walking alone and burn more calories because in includes the large muscles of the trunk. Using the poles also takes some strain off of the lower extremity joints.
- Resistance training is also important when you are trying to change your body composition and lower your bodyfat percentage.
- High Intensity Interval Training (HIIT) - Once you are in better condition and have a method of exercise that allows you to increase the intensity of exercise, (and clearance from your doctor with safe target exercise heart rate parameters), beginning HIIT will add efficiency to your workouts.

One thing you do not want to do is to continue an exercise that causes pain.  This can lead to an injury as you fear and cause you to stop exercising all together.

Here are 2 other question/answers that go beyond your question but may help you with your program.  Good luck.
[Weight Loss when Obese](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/how-to-lose-weight-when-morbidly-obese/6374#6374) and [Getting Back in Shape](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-an-overweight-engineer-get-back-in-shape/2058#2058)

Comment: You are welcome.  After you check with your doctor and are ready to run, you can also learn more about [running form](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/is-there-a-recommended-running-technique-if-youre-overweight) and [running shoes](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/what-are-the-main-types-of-running-shoes-and-which-should-i-select)